# Registering a BackgroundService from a Type

Tags: asp.net-core

Is there any way to register a background service from a type?
With the code below, if I remove the cast to `BackgroundService`, the code won't compile.

As it stands below, then I only get a single one of the services from the array registered.

If I change it to `IHostedService`, then I receive this exception.

```
System.ArgumentException: Implementation type cannot be 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService' because it is indistinguishable from other services registered for 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService'. (Parameter 'descriptor')
```

My code:

```
.ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    Type[] backgroundServices = GetBackgroundServices(assemblies).ToArray();
                    foreach (var @type in backgroundServices)
                        services.AddHostedService((ihs) => (BackgroundService)ihs.GetRequiredService(@type));
                })
```

Thanks very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extension `AddHostedService` [simply does this](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions/ServiceCollectionHostedServiceExtensions.cs):

```
services.AddTransient<IHostedService, THostedService>();
```

Where `THostedService` is a class that implements `IHostedService`.

So, if you wanted to inject a hosted service by type, you would simply do:

```
services.AddTransient(typeof(IHostedService), typeof(MyBackgroundService));
```

`MyBackgroundService` in this case would need to be set up as either this:

```
public class MyBackgroundService : IHostedService { ... }
```

Or this:

```
public class MyBackgroundService : BackgroundService { ... }
```

`BackgroundService` implements `IHostedService`... so both of theses cases would work with the above method.

Comment: Thanks Andy. That's great. Out of interest, I had to use    services.AddTransient(typeof(IHostedService), @type);. If I used BackgroundService instead of IHostedService, there were no errors but the services didn't run

Comment: @DamienSawyer -- I am trying to follow what you are saying. You implemented `BackgroundService`, but it wouldn't run? So you had to implement `IHostedService`? It should work in either case. `BackgroundService` is just an `IHostedService` If you want to update your question showing how you implement/inject a `BackgroundService` i would be more than happy to take a look. For reference: https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions/BackgroundService.cs

Comment: Hi Andy
This worked:
services.AddTransient(typeof(IHostedService), @type);
This did not. It compiled ok, but the services (which inheritted from BackgroundService) did not run. 
services.AddTransient(typeof(BackgroundService), @type);
Thanks

Comment: @DamienSawyer -- you can't do it like this: `services.AddTransient(typeof(BackgroundService), @type);`, You have to do it like this: `services.AddTransient(typeof(IHostedService), @type);` Even if type implements `BackgroundService`, you still have to send `IHostedService` as the interface type.